# Magento2: Is it possible to add configurable product in group product?

Tags: magento2, product

Can you please suggest some idea that how to add configurable product in group product?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
But you can add all of the simple products that belong to the configurable product into your grouped product.
You will achieve a similar result.
your clients will still be able to select the configuration they want.